# IMGUR API v3 ID for Javascript Uploader Not Working?

Tags: javascript

I volunteer on a forum whose members are largely seniors, so can be technology challenged. Our outdated cold fusion forum software doesn't allow uploading photos, but does permit embedding from external sites such as IMGUR. I'm looking for a simple drag and drop Javascript based uploader, and found this free to use simple script from Paul Rouge at https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/the-shortest-image-uploader-ever/.

```
function upload(file) {

// file is from a <input> tag or from Drag'n Drop
// Is the file an image?

if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

// It is!
// Let's build a FormData object

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
fd.append("key", "6528448c258cff474ca9701c5bab6927");
// Get your own key: http://api.imgur.com/

// Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
xhr.onload = function() {
// Big win!
// The URL of the image is:
JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
}
// Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
// And now, we send the formdata
xhr.send(fd);
}
```

The script works fine using his Client ID for API v2, but I have not been able to get it to work with my Client ID using IMGUR API v3?  Tried updating with "Authentication" "Client-ID ", setting IMGUR path to "https://api.imgur.com/3/image", etc. but no luck?

Anyone know how to make this work? Or otherwise, know of a another similar Javascript IMGUR uploader(client side)?  I apologize for not being very adept with scripting?

Thanks for your assistance.